# How to send message for incoming missed call numbers, in iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to develop an app that is for sending message for incoming missed calls (such as: I am busy, call me later)?

Is there any possibility to detect the incoming calls through my application automatically?

I am going to upload my application in AppStore; so, I can not use any private library. I have searched on Stack Overflow for this questions; but, I hope there may be any update on this.

Can any one help me please?

Comment: It might work in iOS 10 with CallKit extension.

Comment: can we get the incomming call number using this extension @ Vaionixx